# OMNet++ to send packet from one node to another node and to record packets sent and energy consumption as graph

Tags: networking, nodes, simulation, sensors, omnet++

I am using OMNet++ to simulate a wireless network. The code is below:

**NED FILE**

```
import inet.common.figures.DelegateSignalConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.INetworkNode;
import inet.physicallayer.contract.packetlevel.IRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.integrated.IntegratedCanvasVisualizer;

network WirelessA
{
    parameters:
        string hostType = default("WirelessHost");
        string mediumType = default("IdealRadioMedium");
        @display("bgb=2500,2500;bgg=100,1,grey95");
        @figure[title](type=label; pos=0,-1; anchor=sw; color=darkblue);
        @figure[rcvdPkText](type=indicatorText; pos=900,50; anchor=w; font=,50; textFormat="Packets Received: %g"; initialValue=0);
        //@statistic[rcvdPk](source=hostB_rcvdPk; record=figure(count); targetFigure=rcvdPkText);
        //@signal[hostB_rcvdPk];
        //@delegatesignal[rcvdPk](source=hostB.udpApp[0].rcvdPk; target=hostB_rcvdPk);
    submodules:
        visualizer: IntegratedCanvasVisualizer {
            @display("p=2400,50");
        }
        configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=2400,250");
        }
        radioMedium: <mediumType> like IRadioMedium {
            @display("p=2400,450");
        }
        figureHelper: DelegateSignalConfigurator {
            @display("p=2400,650");
        }
        BaseStation: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=1200,1200;i=device/antennatower");
        }
        SubStationA: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=600,650;i=device/receiverdish");
        }
        SubStationB: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=1750,600;i=device/receiverdish");
        }
        SubStationC: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=1700,1700;i=device/receiverdish");
        }
        SubStationD: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=650,1750;i=device/receiverdish");
        }
        SensorNodeA1: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=875,900;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeA2: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=425,975;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeA3: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=225,625;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeA4: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=475,275;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeA5: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=875,450;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeB1: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=1875,300;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeB2: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=1450,425;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeB3: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=1475,850;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeB4: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=1925,925;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeB5: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=2100,575;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeC1: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=1425,1950;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeC2: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=1450,1500;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeC3: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=1875,2075;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeC4: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=2100,1750;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeC5: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=1900,1400;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeD1: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=800,2075;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeD2: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=1000,1700;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeD3: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=650,1450;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeD4: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=350,2050;i=device/device");
        }
        SensorNodeD5: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=275,1625;i=device/device");
        }
}
```

**INI FILE**

```
[Config Wireless01]
description = Militart Based WSN Model
network = WirelessA
sim-time-limit = 5s

*.BaseStation.networkLayer.arpType = "GlobalARP"
*.SubStation*.networkLayer.arpType = "GlobalARP"
*.SensorNode**.networkLayer.arpType = "GlobalARP"

*.BaseStation.wlan[0].typename = "WirelessNic"
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].radioType = "IdealRadio"
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].macType = "CsmaCaMac"
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].mac.useAck = true
#*.BaseStation.wlan[0].mac.fullDuplex = false
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 1300m
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].radio.receiver.ignoreInterference = true
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].radio.displayCommunicationRange = true
*.BaseStation.**.bitrate = 10Mbps
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumerType = "StateBasedEnergyConsumer"
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.offPowerConsumption = -1mW
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.sleepPowerConsumption = 0mW
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.switchingPowerConsumption = 1mW
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.receiverIdlePowerConsumption = 2mW
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.receiverBusyPowerConsumption = 5mW
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.receiverReceivingPowerConsumption = 10mW
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.transmitterIdlePowerConsumption = 2mW
*.BaseStation.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.transmitterTransmittingPowerConsumption = 100mW
*.BaseStation.energyStorageType = "IdealEnergyStorage"

*.SubStation*.wlan[0].typename = "WirelessNic"
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].radioType = "IdealRadio"
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].macType = "CsmaCaMac"
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].mac.useAck = true
#*.SubStation*.wlan[0].mac.fullDuplex = true
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 600m
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].radio.receiver.ignoreInterference = true
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].radio.displayCommunicationRange = true
*.SubStation*.**.bitrate = 5Mbps
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumerType = "StateBasedEnergyConsumer"
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.offPowerConsumption = -1mW
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.sleepPowerConsumption = 0mW
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.switchingPowerConsumption = 1mW
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.receiverIdlePowerConsumption = 2mW
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.receiverBusyPowerConsumption = 5mW
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.receiverReceivingPowerConsumption = 10mW
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.transmitterIdlePowerConsumption = 2mW
*.SubStation*.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.transmitterTransmittingPowerConsumption = 100mW
*.SubStation*.energyStorageType = "IdealEnergyStorage"

*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].typename = "WirelessNic"
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].radioType = "IdealRadio"
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].macType = "CsmaCaMac"
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].mac.useAck = true
#*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].mac.fullDuplex = true
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 250m
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].radio.displayCommunicationRange = true
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].radio.receiver.ignoreInterference = true
*.SensorNode**.**.bitrate = 1Mbps
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumerType = "StateBasedEnergyConsumer"
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.offPowerConsumption = -1mW
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.sleepPowerConsumption = 0mW
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.switchingPowerConsumption = 1mW
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.receiverIdlePowerConsumption = 2mW
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.receiverBusyPowerConsumption = 5mW
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.receiverReceivingPowerConsumption = 10mW
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.transmitterIdlePowerConsumption = 2mW
*.SensorNode**.wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.transmitterTransmittingPowerConsumption = 100mW
*.SensorNode**.energyStorageType = "IdealEnergyStorage"

*.configurator.addStaticRoutes = false
*.hostType = "AODVRouter"
*.visualizer.dataLinkVisualizer.packetNameFilter = "AODV*"
*.visualizer.mediumVisualizer.displaySignals = true

*.SensorNodeA1.numUdpApps = 1
*.SensorNodeA1.udpApp[0].typename = "UDPBasicApp"
*.SensorNodeA1.udpApp[0].destAddresses = "SubStationA"
*.SensorNodeA1.udpApp[0].destPort = 5000
*.SensorNodeA1.udpApp[0].messageLength = 1000B
*.SensorNodeA1.udpApp[0].sendInterval = exponential(12ms)
*.SensorNodeA1.udpApp[0].packetName = "UDPData"
*.SubStationA.numUdpApps = 1
*.SubStationA.udpApp[0].typename = "UDPSink"
*.SubStationA.udpApp[0].localPort = 5000
```

Here the network is getting created but when i try to send a packet from SensorNodeA1 to SubStationA, during simulation the packet is sent from SensorNodeA1 to all the nodes. What should i do to send a packet from one node to another single node? Also i want to record and then draw graph of the packets sent over time and the energy consumption of each nodes. I am still new to OMNet++ so if someone can guide me it will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

You do know that in wireless scenarios, a message is always "broadcasted" on the wireless medium, hence the message goes to all receivers in radio range.
Depending on your wireless radio medium model, it might also go to receivers in the interference range to compute the level of interference.
There is no "unicast" in wireless, it is a shared medium where everybody can receive everything if he is on the same frequency, knows the modulation etc.

"Unicast" or "Multicast" can only be enabled on the higher levels, e.g. through addressing, just like you do it with the destination address "SubStationA".
Check the outputs from the other nodes that receive the packet, do they really receive it on their application layers or do they discard it at the MAC layer due to a different destination address?
Then again, if some kind of forwarding or routing protocol is used, nodes might forward a packet anyway...

As for the statistical recording, check the [OMNeT manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#cha:ana-sim) for information about this complex part.

Most of the existing INET simulation models have various statistics already included, so once you enable the statistics that you want (via your `omnetpp.ini` file), you can check out the created result files (scalar or vector, depending on the type of data you want to record - again [check the OMNeT simulation manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ana-sim:result-file-formats)) and use the included analysis tools to filter your data and print graphs.

If your statistics aren't already included, you can add them manually, which is not really complicated. Based on your code, I guess you already checked out the INET wireless tutorial - step 8 - modeling wireless consumption (https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/tutorials/wireless/step8.html), so simply follow the tutorial and maybe in addition the TicTocTutorial part about statistics (https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/part4.html).